# How can I select the files that should never be pulled to the repository?

Tags: git, repository

How can I select the files that should never be pulled to the repository?

In particular I want this file `myBackend/src/main/resources/application.properties` to be never synchronized because each user put local settings on top of a template `application.properties` stored in the `develop` branch.

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md
    modified:   myBackend/docker-compose.yml
    modified:   myBackend/src/main/resources/application.properties

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    myBackend/udo systemctl start docker

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Also, I have some strange untracked files `myBackend/udo systemctl start docker`. Indeed this is not the file. It was a command written by mistake `udo` instead of `sudo`.

How can I remove it?

Comment: You can use a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file to ignore certain files. [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) removes untracked files from your workspace.

Comment: @kowsky: `fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove local untracked files, [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) is your go to guy.

First run:

```
git clean -n      //This will display the untracked files that will be removed
```

Then run:

```
git clean -f      //To remove the file(s) - Note: Remove here means Delete
```

If it's a directory, do this instead:

```
git clean -fd
```

Lastly, to ignore file(s), simply add them to your `.gitignore` file

So, in your case,

```
Add myBackend/src/main/resources/application.properties to your .gitignore file.
```

Comment: I would like to add that it is a good idea to add a `application.properties.example` or something file to the repository. This file shoud be filled with some default values (which do not need to be proper values, like example.invalid for a domain) so it is easier for other users to recreate the properties file